# Flat profile IDC type connectors and cable replacement

Tags: connector, wiring

Hello guys I am looking to replace IDC connector on my project board with something flatter like the ones found in laptop. The problem as I do not have any guide to go around to look for the right connector. I have tried using right angled IDC as a compromise but I am looking for sth similar so that the cable housing and the IDC connector do not stick out more than 5 mm in height on either side of the pc. Any ideas on replacement will be appreciate. My current connector is 20 line DIP.

Note: The problem with right angled IDC is that it makes disconnecting the cable a perilous endeavour. I have lost two boards because of this :(

I want to use a cable like this [enter link description here](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Camera-CSI-DSI-Flat-Ribbon-Cable-for-the-Raspberry-Pi-Lengths-5cm-to-200cm-/141280713876) But cannot find its housing and latch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for to connect to one of those cables is a FFC or FPC connector.
[image]

http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/connectors/pcb-connectors/fpc-connectors/
http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connectors/1442849

They come in both horizontal & vertical orientations, and surface-mount and through-hole versions (although there seem to be more options in SMD than thru-hole).
When you're choosing one, pay careful attention to the pin pitch (spacing between adjacent pins) as this must match the cable you're planning to use with it.
Also be aware that there are top-contact versions and bottom-contact versions, so you'll need to decide which way you want the exposed ends of your cable to face (up or down) when you plug it in.
Finally, check the thickness of your cable so make sure that it will fit in the allowable range of the connector.

Answer (score 2):

It's called "FPC" or "FFC" - Flexible Printed Circuit, or Flat-Flex Connectors. It's nothing at all like IDC since at no point does the insulation ever get displaced.

[A selection on Farnell UK](http://uk.farnell.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?catalogId=15001&langId=44&storeId=10151&categoryId=700000005015&st=fpc&pageSize=25&showResults=true)